# Making crossdomain XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

could anybody tell me, how can i parse non-auth data from another server?
I have site: aaa.com(example) and wanna get some data from bbb.com. But browser security do not allow this.
Are there any "hacks"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a cross domain request for your own server , then you can use JSONP (JSON with padding) and you can use **jXHR** for making cross domain request , below is the link of **jXHR** :

https://gist.github.com/1576277/f4aead6741e0d7b0c40db6601048d9db6be1a5f9

And here is an example to use jXHR :

```
function sendRequest()
{
    var xhrReq = new jXHR();
    xhrReq.onreadystatechange = function(data)
    {
        if (xhrReq.readyState === 4) 
        {
            //data contains your jsonp response..
        }
    };
    var url = "http://" + SERVER_NAME + "yourCodeFile.aspx?callback=?"; 
    xhrReq.open("GET",url);
    xhrReq.send();
}
```

Always remember to add '**callback=?**' as a query string parameter in url for jXHR request.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make a cross domain request to a server you manage is to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the server.

Following your example, if you enable CORS on bbb.com you will be able to make a request from aaa.com.

See this link for further details: http://enable-cors.org/